# How to plot a dashed line when plotting on a logarithmic scale in R

Tags: r, plot, logarithm, trendline

I am plotting a dataset in R, and have set the y-axis to a log-scale.

My data splits into to trends which I have modelled, and added as trendlines to the chart. When using the simple `lines()` command, it creates the dashed line that is affected by the log-scale.

[image: Plot as it looks]

As can be seen from the figure, when using the simple command `lines(x_1, predict(fit_1), lty = 2, lwd = 1, col = "red", log = "y")`, it creates the dashed line that is impacted by the log scale.

Is there a way to set the dashed line's dashes and spaces to vary with the log-scale to prevent the dashes bunching into a solid line at the centre of the trend line?

The model is literally just a simple expression `y = A*10^(mx)`.

This is purely a cosmetic issue for publication.

Comment: Dashed lines work just fine even with log axes in R. I guess the problem is that your *x* values are not ordered which results in some parts of the line being overdrawn many times. Does `lines(sort(x_1), predict(fit_1)[order(x_1)], lty = 2, lwd = 1, col = "red", log = "y")` look better?

Answer (score 1):

I admit I'm not 100% sure what's going on here since you didn't give us a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Since these are straight lines, could you use just the endpoints?

```r
ends <- function(z) z[c(1, length(z))]
lines(ends(x_1), ends(predict(fit_1)), lty = 2, lwd = 1, 
               col = "red", log = "y")
```

If as @RobertHacken suggests the problem is that the values aren't sorted, we could use

```r
ends <- function(z) z[c(which.min(x_1), which.max(x_1))]
```

(note that the 'ends' of both vectors are determined by the position of the min/max of `x_1`)